# How to disable flapdoodle embedded mongodb in certain tests

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, junit, spring-data

I created a spring boot application based on [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) (gradle flavour).

I also added

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
```

To use a MongoDB for persistence. I also added a simple integration test that works fine:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TileServiceApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private UserSettingRepository userSettingRepository;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws Exception {
        Folder folder = random( Folder.class, "color", "elements" );
        EserviceTile eserviceTile1 = random( EserviceTile.class , "color");
        EserviceTile eserviceTile2 = random( EserviceTile.class, "color" );
        folder.setElements( Arrays.asList(eserviceTile1) );
        TileList usersTiles = new TileList( Arrays.asList( folder, eserviceTile2 ) );

        userSettingRepository.save( new UserSetting( "user1", usersTiles ));


        String string = mvc.perform( get( "/user1" ) ).andExpect( status().isOk() ).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
        Assert.assertThat(string, allOf( containsString( eserviceTile1.getName() ), containsString( eserviceTile2.getName() ) ) );
    }

}
```

If a mongodb is running on default port i see the data persisted. To be 
independent of running mongo i just added:

```
 testCompile('de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:2.1.1')
```

and voila the test runs without mongo! (nothing else to add)

My problem is: **I want to disable the embedded Mongo for certain tests**. What is the easiest way to achieve that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Embedded Mongo daemon is started with `EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration`. You can disable daemon start in a single test by excluding `EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration` from scan:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration")
public class DoNotStartMongoTest {
    //...

    @Test
    public void test() {
    }
}
```

I would prefer an opposite functionality: start embedded Mongo daemon on demand. To do this you need to exclude `EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration` in production code:

```
@EnableMongoRepositories
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)
public class MySpringBootApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Then in test code add annotation which will enable embedded Mongo daemon start:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(TYPE)
@Import(EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)
public @interface EnableEmbeddedMongo {
}
```

And annotate your test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EnableEmbeddedMongo
public class StartMongoTest {
    //...

    @Test
    public void test() {
    }
}
```

Comment: It is kind of funny to add test related data to production code though, agree it makes much more sense to to turn it on, than turn it off in tests

Comment: Using this approach I figured out that `@DataMongoTest` already does what `@EnableEmbeddedMongo` aims for. Which makes the idea of deactivating the auto configuration in the first place a great one