# Spring autoconfigure.exclude not working on Apple Silicon M1 when running tests

Tags: spring, spring-test, apple-m1, apple-silicon, flapdoodle-embed-mongo

I'm working on Spring Webflux, Kotlin, Mongo Project.

I'm using [EmbeddedMongoDB](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo) to back DB in test codes.

Because spring tests automatically use EmbeddedMongoDB when not configured, we had to always exclude it like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604062/how-to-disable-flapdoodle-embedded-mongodb-in-certain-tests) suggests.

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration
```

For test cases that needs EmbeddedMongoDB, I made a custom annotation class just like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604062/how-to-disable-flapdoodle-embedded-mongodb-in-certain-tests)'s answer.

```kotlin
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@Import(EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration::class)
annotation class EnableEmbeddedMongo
```

But when I ran tests that don't need EmbeddedMongoDB on Apple Silicon M1 macbooks, the default exclusion doesn't work, and embeddedMongoDB would just start even when I didn't attached `EnableEmbeddedMongo` annotation.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is related to Apple Silicon. The only thing I encountered in a little over year working with M1 is that you need to update your JVM to a M1 capable.

Probably this will do the trick for you:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.mongodb.embedded.version=3.5.5")
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70443590/6500730