# @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude =...) on tests failed in Spring Boot 2.6.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I tried to upgrade my data-mongo example project to Spring Boot 2.6.0. There is a test designed to run against Testcontainers, I also included the embedded mongo dep for other tests, so I have to exclude the AutoConfiguration for embedded mongo to make sure this test working on Docker/testcontainers.

**The following configuration worked well with Spring Boot 2.5.6**.

```java
@DataMongoTest
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {MongodbContainerInitializer.class})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)
@Slf4j
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class PostRepositoryTest {}
```

But after upgrading to Spring Boot 2.6.0 and running the application, I got the exception like this.

```sh
[           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: o
rg.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedMongoServer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfig
ure/mongo/embedded/EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'embeddedMongoServer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.bea
ns.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedMongoConfiguration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/embedded/Embed
dedMongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [de.flap
doodle.embed.mongo.config.MongodConfig]: Factory method 'embeddedMongoConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Set the spring.mongodb.embedd
ed.version property or define your own MongodConfig bean to use embedded MongoDB
```

Obviously, `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude =...)` did not affect the context in tests when upgrading to Spring Boot 2.6.0.

**Update**: Temporarily resolved it, see my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `@ImportAutoConfiguration(exclude = ...)` or `@DataMongoTest(excludeAutoConfiguration = ...)` on test classes to overcome this barrier when upgrading to Spring Boot 2.6.0.

```java
@DataMongoTest
@ImportAutoConfiguration(exclude = EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)
//other config are ommitted
public class PostRepositoryTest {}

//or 
@DataMongoTest(excludeAutoConfiguration = EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)
public class PostRepositoryTest {}
```

Answer (score 20):

Just add:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.mongodb.embedded.version=3.5.5")
```

annotation **before** your **Unit Test** and it will start working.

@Henning's answer has a good explanation of why you need this.

Comment: You did not understand my original question as well, my purpose is disabling embedded mongo in my test which used testcontainers to serve a Mongo service in the background.

Comment: @Igor, can I ask you from where get the version? I could not find the place where I could see different versions.

Comment: It is a good question, @RamPrakash. I have spent some time looking for the latest version but was not able to find much. Here is the code where this version is used: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/b94fcd1ad7d2b2ec07500680934b3b24f8c8dc0e/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/embedded/EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.java#L162

Answer (score 11):

As of Spring Boot 2.6, the property `spring.mongodb.embedded.version` must be set to use the auto-configured embedded MongoDB. It's mentioned in the release notes: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#embedded-mongo

This is also what the error message you posted, advises to do: `Set the spring.mongodb.embedd ed.version property or define your own MongodConfig bean to use embedded MongoDB`

The annotation `@DataMongoTest` is meta-annotated with `@ImportAutoConfiguration` and `@AutoConfigureDataMongo`, and is designed to trigger auto-configuration of MongoDB unless explicitly disabled as you do in the working configuration examples.

In your first configuration example, the annotation `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)` does not override this effect of `@DataMongoTest`.

With Spring Boot 2.5.6, the auto-configured `MongodConfig` bean is most likely also part of the application context but not effectively used. But this depends on the rest of the code and in particular on the `MongodbContainerInitializer`.

Comment: I know well about the changes of Spring Boot 2.6.0 and know it is a must to set `spring.mongodb.embedded.version` if using embedded mongo in tests, but here the problem concern is `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude ="...")` does not work with `@DataMongoTest`.

Comment: Did you get this figured out? I'm trying to make it work for testing with flapfoodle, but failing.

Comment: @MattRaible check my [working example](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/boot-data-mongo/src/test/java/com/example/demo/PostRepositoryWithEmbeddedMongoTest.java).