# Spring's ConstructorResolver#instantiateUsingFactoryMethod ignoring spring.mongodb.embedded.version for embedded mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying to run a Spring Boot application with an embedded mongodb (not just for testing, but live). It was working fine until I decided to modernize to use latest available Spring jars, etc. Upgrading to Spring Boot 2.6.1 I now get an '**IllegalStateException: Set the spring.mongodb.embedded.version property or define your own MongodConfig bean to use embedded MongoDB**' from **EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration#determineVersion**, where my application.properties entry for 'spring.mongodb.embedded.version=3.6.3' is being reported as null. Tracing back to **ConstructorResolver#instantiateUsingFactoryMethod** I see it passes in an **EmbeddedMongoProperties** with null 'version'. That method is way over my head but I believe it is the cause. I suspect it's somehow using the older **MongoProperties** which does not have version but I'm not sure. I've been debugging for hours and I'm not getting anywhere fast. Any help appreciated.

application.properties:

```
server.port=8090

spring.mongodb.embedded.version=3.6.3
spring.mongodb.embedded.features=SYNC_DELAY,NO_HTTP_INTERFACE_ARG
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver
#spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=jokes
spring.data.mongodb.host=127.0.0.1
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
#spring.data.mongodb.username=craig
#spring.data.mongodb.password=***
#spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.mongodb.embedded.storage.database-dir=/home/craig/.ca.footeware.web-mongodb/
```

pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <!-- exclude junit 4 -->
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-imaging</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha2</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude =...) on tests failed in Spring Boot 2.6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70047380/enableautoconfigurationexclude-on-tests-failed-in-spring-boot-2-6-0)

Comment: I don't know. I gave up on using embedded mongodb on live system and moved to proper external mongodb. I'm still using embedded for integration tests and it works fine. Thanks for responding though.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below lines to test class.

```
@DataMongoTest
@ImportAutoConfiguration(exclude = EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Comment: As I stated above, I've refactored the project to not use embedded mongodb.